# Return several models into a view with model type IList<> in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, ilist

I have 2 models that represent 2 different tables in database. I would like to change these 2 models in one view. I know I can combine the 2 models into one and pass it to the view, but my view should accept `IList<>`. The problem is that I am not sure how to use combined model in view.
My combined model looks like this:

```
public class FORM2_COMMON
{
    public IEnumerable<FORM_2_SEC_1> FORM2_SEC1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FORM_2_SEC_2> FORM2_SEC2 { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult EditReport(ReportParam param)
{
  FORM2_COMMON common = new FORM2_COMMON();
  common.FORM2_SEC1 = db.FORM_2_SEC_1.Where(e => e.YEAR == param.Year && e.MONTH == param.SelectedMonth).OrderBy(e => e.LINE_CODE).ToList();
  common.FORM2_SEC2 = db.FORM_2_SEC_2.Where(e => e.YEAR == param.Year && e.MONTH == param.SelectedMonth).OrderBy(e => e.LINE_CODE).ToList();

   return PartialView(common);
 }
```

And then the form is sumbitted:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EditReportSubmit(FORM2_COMMON report)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (FORM_2_SEC_1 sec1 in report.FORM2_SEC1)
            {
                db.Entry(sec1).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            foreach (FORM_2_SEC_2 sec2 in report.FORM2_SEC2)
            {
                db.Entry(sec2).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ReportForm2", "OPSReports");
        }
        return View(report);

    }
```

In view:

```
@model Proj.Models.FORM2_COMMON

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) //confused here
{
            <tr> </tr>
}
```

Now in view I don't know how to iterate through `Model.FORM2_SEC1` and `Model.FORM2_SEC2` separately.

Everything is easy when I pass one model to the view, I usually code like this:

```
 @model IList<FORM_2_SEC_1>

 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
 {
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x[i].TITLE)</td>
                     ......
                 </tr>
  }
```

And I also have Editor template for the model (`FORM_2_SEC_1.cshtml`):

```
@model FORM_2_SEC_1

<tr>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TITLE)</td>
    .......
</tr>
```

So how can I apply the same logic for my combined model?

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties through the model like: `Model.FORM2_SEC1.xxx`

```
@model Proj.Models.FORM2_COMMON

// iterate FORM2_SEC1 - same goes for FORM2_SEC2.
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.FORM2_SEC1.Count(); i++) 
{
            <tr> </tr>
}
```

or use a foreach loop, which gives direct access to item rather than accessing it through an index.

```
@foreach(var item in Model.FORM2_SEC1)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.SomeValue</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This approach will be the same for FORM2_SEC1, and FORM2_SEC2, since they are both a list.

**EDIT:**

List is empty on postback.

Try adding a set of hidden values to populate the static fields of your object.

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.FORM2_SEC1.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => m.FORM2_SEC1[i].Id) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FORM2_SEC1[i].Title)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the error in for loop : Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Comment: Try adding a set of parantheses to Count().

Comment: I cannot access the properties like Model.FORM2_SEC1.xxx because FORM2_SEC1 is IEnumerable

Comment: Where do you get this error? Inside your partial, or when iterating the for() loop?

Comment: I mean I cannot access the fields, for exaple @Model.FORM2_SEC1.TITLE. Ok, now I use foreach loop, but I get null in my controller, when the form is submitted

Comment: You need to either access the object within a foreach loop or by defining it through @Model.FORM2_SEC1.FirstOrDefault().TITLE (this can blow up if the list is empty, handle it appropriately). The report parameter in the POST action EditReportSubmit is null, or just the lists contained in the report parameter?

Comment: I guess you meant not .FirstOrDefault() but .ElementAt(i). I get null in POST action, the lists in 'FORM2_COMMON report' are nulls

Comment: Could you try something like the last edit in the answer? The last paragraph.

Comment: There is an error when applying indexing[] to IEnumerable (FORM2_SEC1[i]). I added all hidden fields needed. I think the problem is in Editor template (last paragraph in my post). It has another structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over your collections with a foreach statement, or a for...

Foreach:

```
@foreach(var x in model.FORM2_SEC1) {
   // Do whatever you want with x
}
```

For:

```
@for(int i=0;i<model.FORM2_SEC1.Count;i++) {
   // Do whatever you want
}
```

However, if you're attempting to edit or display the information, there is a way easier way with razor. Create an editor or display template: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx

Then you can just call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FORM2_SEC1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use foreach loop but I get null in controller [HttpPost] method when the form is submitted. Should I change Editor template as well?